# Qual é o propósito da classe RecyclerView.Adapter ao utilizar o RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

Para utilizar o **RecylerView** do Android precisamos criar uma classe `CustomAdapter` que estende da classe abstrata `RecyclerView.Adapter` em seguida implementar três métodos que são:

- `onCreateViewHolder`
- `onBindViewHolder`
- `getItemCount`

O método `getItemCount` eu sei que retorna a quantidade de itens no RecyclerView, porém, a própria classe Adapter e os métodos `onCreateViewHolder` e `onBindViewHolder` me deixa confuso e com dúvidas em relação ao seus propósitos e funcionamentos, essas dúvidas serão abordadas abaixo.

## Dúvidas

1. Qual é o propósito da classe `CustomAdapter` quando vamos utilizar o
   RecyclerView?
2. Qual é a finalidade do método `onCreateViewHolder`?
3. Qual é a finalidade do método `onBindViewHolder`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Qual é o proposito da classe CustomAdapter quando vamos utilizar o
>   RecyclerView?

Inicialmente *[Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html)*, ou adaptador, vamos dizer assim, é responsável por fazer uma exibição para cada item em um conjunto de dados. Ou seja, um ele representa a ligação entre a *View* e alguma fonte de dados, que geralmente vêm em dois tipos: representados por dados baseadas em *array’s* ou listas; ou representandos por dados baseados em cursor.

Com isso em mente, o nome *CustomAdapter* já expressa seu significado, deixando explicito que trata de um tipo de `Adapter`, porém customizado, ou seja, um adaptador personalizado. Existe o [SimpleAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html), é um simples adaptador usado para personalização de itens de lista ou grade. Esse adaptador funciona como uma ponte entre uma `AdapterView` e os dados destinados para essa `View`. O `CustomAdapter` é um pouco além, pois ele dá mais autoridade em relação as *views*, para que possa fazer qualquer tipo de modificação no item.

> Qual é a finalidade do método onCreateViewHolder?

O método [`onCreateViewHolder()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onCreateViewHolder(android.view.ViewGroup,%20int)) serve para para inflar o *layout* do item. Basicamente é chamado quando é necessário criar um novo item.

> Qual é a finalidade do método onBindViewHolder?

O método [`onBindViewHolder()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int,%20java.util.List%3Cjava.lang.Object%3E)) tem a finalidade de definir os atributos de exibição com base nos dados. Basicamente é invocado quando um item precisa ser exibido para o usuário.

Answer (score 3):

> Qual é o proposito da classe CustomAdapter quando vamos utilizar o RecyclerView?

Uma RecyclerView deve ser capaz de apresentar visualmente uma variedade de tipos de dados e de formas diferentes.
Para que isso seja possível de implementar de forma fácil, a RecyclerView, usa um objecto do tipo [RecyclerView.Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html).
A sua função é pegar nos dados, provenientes de uma fonte de dados qualquer, e "transformá-los" nas *views* a serem usadas pela RecyclerView.

> Qual é a finalidade do método onCreateViewHolder?
>   Qual é a finalidade do método onBindViewHolder?

Esses dois métodos são o "coração" do adapter, é a sua implementação que serve o propósito do adapter.

O método `onCreateViewHolder()` é chamado pela RecyclerView quando ela necessita de uma view nova.
O método `onBindViewHolder()` é chamado pela RecyclerView quando ela necessita que novos dados sejam atribuídos a uma view.

Ambos usam um objecto [RecyclerView.ViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html) onde "estão guardadas" as views.
No método `onCreateViewHolder()` é criado o ViewHolder que depois é passado ao método `onBindViewHolder()` quando é necessário atribuir dados às views.
O uso do ViewHolder, em conjunto com os dois métodos, permite que views não mais usadas possam ser reaproveitadas quando necessário.