# Dados desaparecem ao mover scroll RecyclerView com Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Ola pessoal eu está criando um bate-papo com Firebase e listagem com o RecyclerView, para listar as mensagens mas estou com um problema é que, ao mover ou rolar o RecyclerView algumas mensagens desaparecem, por favor me ajudem a resolver isto!

Aqui está meu codigo e as imagens do resultado:

```
//onCreate 
    ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
            // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI] 
            Model.clear(); 
            getAllTask(dataSnapshot); 
            // ... 
        } 

        @Override 
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { 
            // Getting Post failed, log a message 
            Log.w("TAG", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException()); 
            // ... 
        } 
    }; 

    mData.child("UTILADMIN").addValueEventListener(postListener); 
//end onCreate 

    private void getAllTask(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){ 
        for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){ 

            ModelMessage modelMessage = singleSnapshot.getValue(ModelMessage.class); 
            Model.add(modelMessage); 
            Adapters adaptador = new Adapters(this, Model, mImageLoader, mUser.getUid()); 
            adaptador.notifyItemInserted(Model.size() - 1); 
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptador); 
            linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(Model.size() - 1); 
        } 
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

onBindViewHolder Resolvido:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolders holder, int position) {
    if(Mensagem.get(position).getId().equalsIgnoreCase(this.Id)){


        holder.chat1.setVisibility(view.GONE); //RelativeLayout chat1 INVISIVEL
        holder.chat2.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);//RelativeLayout chat2 VISIVEL
        holder.Nome2.setText(Mensagem.get(position).getNome());
        holder.TextMensagem2.setText(Mensagem.get(position).getMensagem());
    }else{

        holder.chat1.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);//RelativeLayout chat2 VISIVEL
        holder.chat2.setVisibility(view.GONE);//RelativeLayout chat1 INVISIVEL
        holder.Nome1.setText(Mensagem.get(position).getNome());
        holder.TextMensagem1.setText(Mensagem.get(position).getMensagem());
    }
}
```

Comment: Edite a pergunta e acrescente o código do adapter

Comment: pronto esta ai meu adapter se poder dizer o que estou fazendo de errado eu te agradeço muito!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu código está um pouco confuso para dar uma resposta usando ele.

No entanto, esse tipo de problema ocorre quando no `onBindViewHolder()` se usa um ou mais caminhos(if/else) para fazer o *bind*.

Isso acontece porque a RecyclerView reaproveita(recicla, daí o nome) as *views* que usa para os itens.
A RecyclerView cria apenas o número de views necessário para o número de itens que pode apresentar em simultâneo.
Verificará que o problema só acontece quando a lista tem um número de itens que obriga ao uso do *scroll*.

Para tornar o processo mais eficiente ela usa o [Padrão View Holder](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/238101/2541).
É usado um objecto *RecyclerView.ViewHolder* onde "estão guardadas" as *views*.
No método `onCreateViewHolder()` é criado o ViewHolder que depois é passado ao método `onBindViewHolder()` quando é necessário atribuir dados às *views*.

O uso do *ViewHolder*, em conjunto com os dois métodos, permite que *views* não mais usadas possam ser reaproveitadas quando necessário.
Quando o ViewHolder é passado ao método `onBindViewHolder()`, se este se referir a uma *view* reaproveitada, ele virá com os sues atributos já preenchidos.
Se a eles não forem correctamente atribuídos os novos valores, "coisas estranhas acontecerão", nomeadamente repetição de valores iguais em linhas diferentes.

Assim, tem de garantir que, tanto no `if` como no `else`, o ViewHolder tem todos os valores necessários atribuídos.
Por exemplo, suponha que a condição quando é verdadeira(bloco `if`) implica que uma *view* seja escondida então no bloco `else` tem de a tornar visível. Caso contrário quando essa *view* é reaproveitada terá o estado que tinha na linha original.

Veja também: [Qual é o proposito da classe RecyclerView.Adapter ao utilizar o RecyclerView?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/238143/2541)

Comment: Bom ramaral obrigado por responder minha pergunta, o que eu estou tentando fazer é que se o id for iqual ao meu id ele mostrará o balao do lado direito caso contrário ele me mostrará no lado esquerdo ele mostra as duas mensagens normalmente mas quando move para baixo e para cima alguns desaparecem. vou colocar mas uma imagem na pergunta.

Comment: você poderia me dar uma dica?

Comment: Observação quando tenho poucas conversas da tudo ok mas quando tem muitas acontece isso.

Comment: Em relação às fotos, se entendi bem o código, existem duas: uma para a esquerda e outra para a direita e apenas uma é usada de cada vez em função do id. Assim, sempre que usar `holder.Foto.setVisibility(view.GONE);` tem de usar `holder.Foto2.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);`(no bloco if) e vice~versa(no bloco else).

Comment: ok vou ver aqui

Comment: Valew irmão eu editei como você havia dito e deu certo muito obrigado!

Comment: Algo tão simples e eu aqui batendo cabeça muito obrigado!

Comment: As coisas tornam-se simples quando conhecemos o que está "por de trás". Veja a edição da resposta onde tentei explicar porque isso acontece.